# Limit of Recursive Function (Methodology)

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

### Goal:

Find
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d_{n+1}^2$$
where
$$d_{n+1}^2 = d_n^2 + r^2 - 2 \cdot r \cdot d_n \cdot \cos \theta$$
for constant $r$ and $\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

### Attempt:

\begin{align*}
                a &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d_{n+1}^2 \\
                &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d_n^2 + r^2 - 2 d_n r \cos \theta \\
                &= a + r^2 - 2 r \cos \theta \sqrt{a} \\
                &= \frac{r^2}{4 \cdot \cos^2 \theta}
\end{align*}

### Questions:

I know this is the correct answer from running simulations but I'm not confident in the limit approach I'm using. First of all, I know that the limit diverges for $\theta \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$ but I never (knowingly) use the fact that $\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ in the proof. So what is going on here? Is there a different approach I should take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works perfectly only if the limit exists. If the limit doesn't exist, then this approach can give you an answer even though the limit doesn't make sense. So you've implicitly used $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ in assuming that $a$ makes sense.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. But how would I show the limit exists? I could show that the function is bounded and monotonic but that seems like overkill.

Comment: So, to show it diverges for $\theta\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$, note that $-2rd_n\cos(\theta)\geq 0$, so $d_{n+1}^2\geq d_n^2+r^2$, and so $d_n^2\geq d_0^2+nr^2$, which clearly diverges. For the convergent case, I'm not sure it is monotonic, but that would be the easiest option I can think of if it is monotonic

Comment: okay, thank you!

Comment: It is also worth noting that we need $\theta>0$, otherwise this doesn't necessarily converge. This can also be considered as a geometric problem, as the recursion is cosine rule, so we can consider $d_n+1,d_n,r$ as sides of a triangle, so there might be a geometric argument for convergence.

Comment: Definitely, I forgot to mention that in the conditions.